# JSON одинарные кавычки

Tags: javascript, json

Здравствуйте. Встречаю два различных типа файлов JSON  в различной литературе по этому формату.

1.

```
'{"title":"Конференция","date":"2014-11-30T12:00:00.000Z"}'
```

2.

```
{"title":"Конференция","date":"2014-11-30T12:00:00.000Z"}
```

Отличие между ними, как видно, в наличии у первого ограждающих одинарных кавычек. По ним и вопрос: как правильно, когда их надо ставить, когда нет, ставятся ли они автоматически при `JSON.stringify();, ну, и если есть ссылка на короткую инструкцию, вообще красота. Пока не нашел ответа, если будет, поделюсь.

Comment: Разница та же, что и между `123` и `'123'`. Первое - число, второе - строка.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.

```
'{"title":"Конференция","date":"2014-11-30T12:00:00.000Z"}';
```

Строковое представление JSON, получаемое методом stringify.

2.

```
{"title":"Конференция","date":"2014-11-30T12:00:00.000Z"};
```

"Чистый" JSON-объект, используемый к примеру в JavaScript.

Почитать можно [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/json#%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-json-parse) и [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/json#%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-json-stringify)

Answer (score 1):

В [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627) ничего про ограждающие кавычки нет -

```
   These are the six structural characters:

      begin-array     = [ left square bracket

      begin-object    = { left curly bracket

      end-array       = ] right square bracket

      end-object      = } right curly bracket

      name-separator  = : colon

      value-separator = , comma

   Insignificant whitespace is allowed before or after any of the six
   structural characters.
```

Answer (score 1):

В кавычках json представляет из себя строку формата string в неких языка программирования. В то время как без, это обычная форма json. 
Но могу ошибаться